# Web Terminal is not appearing in management portal

Tags: intersystems-iris

I am running IRIS from docker container and I am not getting Web Terminal Option in management portal.

What to do for Web Terminal to be appear in management portal?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not included in the vanilla IRIS image.
But you can install it via InterSystems ZPM:

```
zpm "install webterminal"
```